# Logistic Regression using Gradient Descent with OCTAVE

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I've gone through few courses of Professor Andrew for machine Learning and viewed the transcript for Logistic Regression using Newton's method. However when implementing the logistic regression using gradient descent I face certain issue.

The graph generated is not convex.

My code goes as follows:

I am using the vectorized implementation of the equation.

```
%1. The below code would load the data present in your desktop to the octave memory 
x=load('ex4x.dat');
y=load('ex4y.dat');

%2. Now we want to add a column x0 with all the rows as value 1 into the matrix.
%First take the length
m=length(y);
x=[ones(m,1),x];

alpha=0.1;
max_iter=100;
g=inline('1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z))');

theta = zeros(size(x(1,:)))';   % the theta has to be a 3*1 matrix so that it can multiply by x that is m*3 matrix
j=zeros(max_iter,1);            % j is a zero matrix that is used to store the theta cost function j(theta)

for num_iter=1:max_iter
    %  Now we calculate the hx or hypothetis, It is calculated here inside no. of iteration because the hupothesis has to be calculated for new theta for every iteration
         z=x*theta;
         h=g(z);     % Here the effect of inline function we used earlier will reflect


     j(num_iter)=(1/m)*(-y'* log(h) - (1 - y)'*log(1-h)) ;    % This formula is the vectorized form of the cost function J(theta) This calculates the cost function
         j       
         grad=(1/m) *  x' * (h-y);     % This formula is the gradient descent formula that calculates the theta value.  
         theta=theta - alpha .* grad;          % Actual Calculation for theta
         theta
 end
```

The code per say doesn't give any error but does not produce proper convex graph.

I shall be glad if any body could point out the mistake or share insight on what's causing the problem.

thanks
[image]

Comment: Could you show the graph that it produces?

Comment: I have added the graph, If you connect the dots you find the gradient descent is varying up and down repeatedly, Where as it should decrease and after sometime should remain constant and for that value of j(min j) the theta should be determined. I don't get it when I take the same approach for j approach using Newtons method I get correct output only at 10 iteration. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: About the graph :-   The X-axis is the number of iteration and the Y-axis is the j(theta) cost function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things you need to look into:

1. Machine Learning involves learning patterns from data. If your files ex4x.dat and ex4y.dat are randomly generated, it won't have patterns that you can learn.
2. You have used variables like g, h, i, j which make debugging difficult. Since it's a very small program, it might be a  better idea to rewrite it.

Here's my code that gives the convex plot

```
clc; clear; close all;

load q1x.dat;
load q1y.dat;

X = [ones(size(q1x, 1),1) q1x];
Y = q1y;

m = size(X,1);
n = size(X,2)-1;

%initialize
theta = zeros(n+1,1);
thetaold = ones(n+1,1);

while ( ((theta-thetaold)'*(theta-thetaold)) > 0.0000001 )
    %calculate dellltheta
    dellltheta = zeros(n+1,1);
    for j=1:n+1,
        for i=1:m,
            dellltheta(j,1) = dellltheta(j,1) + [Y(i,1) - (1/(1 + exp(-theta'*X(i,:)')))]*X(i,j);
        end;
    end;
    %calculate hessian
    H = zeros(n+1, n+1);
    for j=1:n+1,
        for k=1:n+1,
                for i=1:m,
                    H(j,k) = H(j,k) -[1/(1 + exp(-theta'*X(i,:)'))]*[1-(1/(1 + exp(-theta'*X(i,:)')))]*[X(i,j)]*[X(i,k)];
                end;
        end;
    end;
    thetaold = theta;
    theta = theta - inv(H)*dellltheta;
    (theta-thetaold)'*(theta-thetaold)
end
```

I get the following values of error after iterations:

```
2.8553
0.6596
0.1532
0.0057
5.9152e-06
6.1469e-12
```

Which when plotted looks like:
[image: Error vs iteration]

Comment: Hi Rishi, I tried the Above problem using Newton's method (hessian) it worked for me too. The challenge i face is to accomplish the convex graph by using Gradient descent. Could you please try the same problem using Gradient Descent.